# Get your “Beta” badge now!

Tags: discussion, badges

Your once in a life time opportunity, getting the [Beta badge](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) for “Drones and Model Aircraft”. It is no longer obtainable after the private beta ends.

It’s requirements are:

> Voted 10 times, added 3 posts score > 0, and visited the site on 3 separate days during the private beta.

Hope to see a lot of these awarded!

Comment: Hellyeah! Let's go, guys! But seriously, don't *just* do it for the silver badge.

Comment: @ifconfig Yeah, do it for the *gold* badges like Electorate and Fanatic ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The badge has now been awarded, congratulations to all [27 users who earned the badge](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta)!

Comment: It should have been awarded to me too!

Answer (score 6):

The [Beta Badge](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) will be awarded soon after the private beta comes to an end. All those who qualify will receive this badge at the same time. I guess it is the way the system is set up.

[Here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) is an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure a lot of us have already met the requirements, but the badge doesn't seem to have been awarded yet for anyone: https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta

Could it be a bug?

Comment: Yes a lot of us have, yay! The badge is usuall awarded at the start of the **public beta**

Comment: I see! It's a bit odd that all the other badges are already awarded and this one has to wait until public beta. But no big deal I suppose.

Comment: It all has to do when a given badge script runs... I guess since the beta badge is only offered for participants during private beta, there's no point in running it all the time... I guess rather than injecting code to check whether a given site is public or private beta or graduated, it's a fairly manual process.

Comment: @anonymous2 I see!

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that back when the badge was first created, the criteria to earn it were undisclosed, so this prevented people from figuring out what they were easily. However, at a later point, they were publicly disclosed.